# Clipping of labels in column chart with negative values

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem where the stack labels in my column chart gets clipped. I have this column chart that displays both negative and positve values. It show percentages compared to a reference data so 0 will be when the column has the same value as the reference data and then it can be either +% or -% compared to that reference data. My problem is that when I have pretty low values for some bars and perhaps 30% on one of the bars the + side of the chart gets it label clipped. Is there any way that I can code around this so that the labels are always fully visible. My customer has as an requirement that the labels should be as they are in the graph, i.e. rotated 90 degrees.

Thanks in advance for any insight for how to solve this issue.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: 'column', animation: false },
        title: { text: null },
        xAxis: { categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'], labels: { style: { fontSize: '1.2em'}} },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false, title: { text: '' },
            labels: { 
                formatter: function () { return this.value === 0 ? '0% (Index)' : this.value + '%'; }, 
                style: { color: '#4572A7'} 
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true, style: { color: 'black', fontSize: '1.2em' },
                formatter: function () { 
                    return this.stack + ((this.total && this.total != 0) ? ': ' +             
                           Math.round(this.total).toFixed(0) + '%' : ''); 
                },
                rotation: -90, x: -5, verticalAlign: 'bottom', align: 'left', textAlign: 'left'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: { column: { stacking: 'normal', pointPadding: 0.3 }, series: { shadow: false, animation: false } },
        tooltip: { enabled: false },
        legend: { borderWidth: 1, shadow: false },
        series: [
            { data: [34, 64, -443], stack: 'Stack 1'}
        ]       
    });
});
```

(See attached jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ewCZa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created simple solution to prevent clipping labels: http://jsfiddle.net/43fBB/

```
        events: {
            load: function(){
                var chart = this,
                    cols = chart.series[0],
                    stacks = chart.yAxis[0].stacks,
                    i,
                    j;
                for(i in stacks){
                    var stack = stacks[i];
                    for(j in stack){
                        var label = stack[j].label,
                            labelBB = label.getBBox(),
                            diff = labelBB.y - labelBB.height;

                        if(diff < 0) {
                            label.attr({
                                translateY:  - diff
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```